# possible to combine two list objects?

Tags: apex, soql

Attempted to solve using wrapper:

```
list<ProductWrapper> pws = new list<ProductWrapper>();
for(product2 p : products) {  
  for(asset_line_items__c b : p.asset_line_items__r) { 
     ProductWrapper pw = new ProductWrapper(p);
     if(b.quantity__c != null) {
          pw.ali = b;
     }
     else{
        //system.debug('products: '+p);
     }
     pws.add(pw);
}
```

Product wrapper class:

```
public class ProductWrapper {

    public Product2 product {get;set;}
    public asset_line_items__c ali {get;set;}    

    public ProductWrapper(Product2 p) {
        product = p;
        ali = new asset_line_items__c();
    }
}
```

END

I have the following SOQL:

```
List<Product2> products = [SELECT Id, Name, cost__c, remaining__c, user__c,isactive,
                        (SELECT Name, quantity__c from asset_line_items__r)
                        FROM Product2];
```

the above soql shows the following results:

[image]

What I want to do is to build the list combining this two:

so the end result should be looks like this:

```
quanity__c name         cost remaining used
8          painted blue 0.25   100       0.0
0          Velona       0.5    100       0.0 //if there is no qty default to 0
5          poli         0.5    100       0.0
0          green        0.75   100       0.0 //if there is no qty default to 0
1          dabra        0.75   100       0.0
0          itum         0.8    100       0.0 //if there is no qty default to 0
1          rican        0.35   100       0.0
1          rican        0.35   100       0.0
```

I have tried with different options using for loop but does not work.

Comment: back to a wrapper? our use formulas to pull the info from Product2 to the Asset Line Item then simply use the line items as the list source and display the formula values

Comment: formulas to pull? sorry did not get it

Comment: i.e Add formula fields on the line item to pull the Product name, cost, and remaining values from the product. Then you can use the line item in a list and display the new formula fields to show the product values. This would give you the multiple lines for rican since you are using the line items as the source of the list

Comment: i can not add or change anything to the object for other reasons, but is there a way you can do with collections? my brain is freez

Comment: You should use a wrapper class like you were doing. You can create whatever you need to do, combine objects, add fields, change field types. The wrapper is a very useful tool and seems to fit this situation well. You could also use two repeats. Once for the list then inside that a repeat for the lines

Comment: i did attempt with wrapper, i will update my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45494/discussion-between-nick-kahn-and-eric).

Comment: Keep working on it. Wrapper is easy to implement here. But you can also do in VF like I have in my answer. From the questions we can tell you are struggling. Thanks for keeping the questions focused. You might benefit from going through the trailhead modules as well. And some of the great articles out there on design patterns etc.

Comment: i just updated my question please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess strictly with visual force you could:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!products}" var="p">

     <apex:repeat value="{!p.Asset_Line_Items__r}" var="ali">

            ..Column to display p.xxx and ali.xxx..
            <apex:column headervalue="Quantity" value="{!ali.Quantity__c}"/>
            <apex:column headervalue="Name" value="{!p.name}"/>
            <apex:column headervalue="Cost" value="{!Cost__c}"/>
            ..Etc..

     </apex:repeat>

</apex:repeat>
```

This basically displays all the line items while preserving access to the parent product2. The display order will be based first on product2 list order then the line item order

Using your code

**Class**

```
list<ProductWrapper> pws = new list<ProductWrapper>();
for(product2 p : products) {  
  //product has not lines so create a wrapper item with default ALI
  if(p.Asset_Line_items__r.isEmpty()){
      pws.add(New ProductWrapper(p,New Asset_Line_Item__c(Quantity__c = 0));
      continue;
  }
  for(asset_line_items__c b : p.asset_line_items__r) { 
     ProductWrapper pw = new ProductWrapper(p,b);
     pws.add(pw);
}
```

**Wrapper**

```
public class ProductWrapper {

    public Product2 product {get;set;}
    public asset_line_items__c ali {get;set;}    

    public ProductWrapper(Product2 p, asset_line_items__c ali) {
        product = p;
        this.ali = ali;
    }
}
```

**VF**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!pws}" var="p">

     <apex:output panel layout="none" rendered="{!p.qty != null>

            ..Column to display p.xxx and ali.xxx..
            <apex:column headervalue="Quantity" value="{!p.ali.Quantity__c}"/>
            <apex:column headervalue="Name" value="{!p.product.name}"/>
            <apex:column headervalue="Cost" value="{!p.produtc.Cost__c}"/>
            ..Etc..

     </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: but the catch is, i do not want to display products if the assetlinitems has qty in it

Comment: @NickKahn - Thats not what you show in your table.

Comment: let me step back, what i meant to say is that lets say product has 7 rows and line item has 5 rows with qty, so at the end the total rows should be displayed is 7, two rows missing qty and 5 rows that have qty, i hope you get the point

Comment: let me give it a shot

Comment: A bit confused. Product and lines are separate. How do you know which products to use? Put a possibility in the answer so check it again